# Laravel 5.4: Redirect::to not working

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5.3

I want to redirect the user to another page if a certain condition is not true.

This is my first/index view:

```
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
      </head>

      <body>


        <?php
        if(5>4) {
        return Redirect::to('controllername@methodname')->with('status','Condition not true!');
        } else {
        ?>
    <p>It is Working</p>

<?php } ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

If I change the condition to (5<4) then it works fine. but if the condition is true, it shows me a blank page. I want to write the condition in the view not in the controller and route. Please Help

Comment: You should verify that in the controller, not in the view.. That condition is true.. of course it will be executed always..

Comment: You can't redirect after you begin an html page syntax. in laravel all redirects should be in controller

Comment: I want to write the condition in the view not in the controller and route.

Comment: What possible reason could you have to put the redirect in your view?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't redirect in the template. It must be in the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect have to be at a place before showing content. You can read this in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redirects) based on phps [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: It was a solution too, but now I've updated my "answer" @MateiMihai

Answer (score 0):

I would to something like this probably:

I would start off by moving you if statement to you controller, as others has pointed out.

Lets say that you render you current view from `HomeController@index`

I would do, in `HomeController`

```
public function index()
{
   if(5>4){
      return redirect()->action('controllername@methodname')->with('status','Condition not true!');
   }else{
      return view('index');
   }
}
```

This will remove your PHP code from the view, and make full use of Laravel route and controller functions.